# Implement bittrex API in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, rest, api

As per Bittrex API Docs it says they use a standard HMAC-SHA512 signing. Append apikey and nonce to your request and calculate the HMAC hash and include it under an apisign header. Note: the nonce is not respected right now but will be enforced later.

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

DEPRECATING
    Request:
    https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=apikey

So to implement this in vb.net i tried following:

```
Dim nonce = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        Dim apiurl = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=" + "apikey" + nonce
        sign = HashString(apiurl, "apisecret")
        Dim request As WebRequest
        request = WebRequest.Create(site)
        Dim response As WebResponse
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.Headers.Add("apisign:" + sign)
        response = request.GetResponse()
```

but getting error :(

{"success":false,"message":"NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}

Comment: "getting error :(" tells us nothing. Post it.

Comment: I'm curious since I'm having an issue with binance right now. What's your error?

Comment: getting {"success":false,"message":"NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim nonce = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString
       Dim apiurl = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=" + "ApiKey" + "&nonce=" + nonce
        sign = HashString(apiurl, "apisecret")
        Dim request As WebRequest
        request = WebRequest.Create(site)
        Dim response As WebResponse
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.Headers.Add("apisign:" + sign)
        response = request.GetResponse()
```

Comment: problem is in nonce... i was sending nonce = DateTime.Now.ToString() but send it as nonce = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()  solve the problem. and also there is a problem in apiurl formating